# Running native adobe XMP on android device

Tags: android, android-ndk, xmp

I am trying to port XMP toolkit over to android device.  I was able to build xmpcore successfully, and have a libXMPCore.so.  When I try to make libXMPFile.so using ndk-build, I am running couple of problems I don't understand.

1) Seems like libXMPFile.so is depended on libXMPCore.so.  I managed to include libXMPCore.so in the Android.mk for libXMPFiles.  My Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Include all cpp file
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
../source/WXMPFiles.cpp \
../source/XMPFiles.cpp \
../source/XMPFiles_Impl.cpp \
../../source/XMP_LibUtils.cpp \
../../source/UnicodeConversions.cpp \
../../source/XML_Node.cpp \
../../third-party/zuid/interfaces/MD5.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/ASF_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/AVCHD_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/RIFF_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/Basic_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/FLV_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/InDesign_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/JPEG_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/MP3_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/MPEG2_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/MPEG4_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/P2_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/PNG_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/PostScript_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/PSD_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/Scanner_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/SonyHDV_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/SWF_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/TIFF_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/Trivial_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/UCF_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/XDCAM_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/XDCAMEX_Handler.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/ASF_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/IPTC_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/MOOV_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/ISOBaseMedia_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/PNG_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/PSIR_FileWriter.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/PSIR_MemoryReader.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/QuickTime_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/Reconcile_Impl.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/ReconcileIPTC.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/ReconcileLegacy.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/ReconcileTIFF.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/RIFF.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/RIFF_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/SWF_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/TIFF_FileWriter.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/TIFF_MemoryReader.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/TIFF_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/XDCAM_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/XMPScanner.cpp \
../source/HandlerRegistry.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/AIFF_Handler.cpp \
../source/FileHandlers/WAVE_Handler.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/ID3_Support.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/AIFF/AIFFBehavior.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/AIFF/AIFFMetadata.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/AIFF/AIFFReconcile.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/IFF/Chunk.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/IFF/ChunkController.cpp\
../source/FormatSupport/IFF/ChunkPath.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/IFF/IChunkBehavior.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/WAVE/BEXTMetadata.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/WAVE/CartMetadata.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/WAVE/Cr8rMetadata.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/WAVE/DISPMetadata.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/WAVE/INFOMetadata.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/WAVE/PrmLMetadata.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/WAVE/WAVEBehavior.cpp \
../source/FormatSupport/WAVE/WAVEReconcile.cpp \
../source/NativeMetadataSupport/IMetadata.cpp \
../source/NativeMetadataSupport/IReconcile.cpp \
../source/NativeMetadataSupport/MetadataSet.cpp \
../source/PluginHandler/FileHandlerInstance.cpp \
../source/PluginHandler/HostAPIImpl.cpp \
../source/PluginHandler/Module.cpp \
../source/PluginHandler/OS_Utils_Linux.cpp \
../source/PluginHandler/PluginManager.cpp \
../source/PluginHandler/XMPAtoms.cpp \
../../source/Host_IO-UNIX.cpp \
../../source/XIO.cpp \
../../source/XMPFiles_IO.cpp \
../public/include/client-glue\TXMPMeta.incl_cpp

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++0x
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../../../android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-     stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/x86/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../../../android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-  stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../../../
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../source
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../source
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../..
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../public/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../XMPFilesPlugins/api/source

LOCAL_LDLIBS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libXMPCore.so

LOCAL_MODULE := xmpfile
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

However, when I tried to run ndk-build, it complains link errors such as:
WXMPFiles.o: in function WXMPFiles_GetXMP_1:/home/w18656/workspace/xline2/main-jb-qcpro-4.2-xline/motorola/hal/ispbypass/xmp/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CS6/XMPFiles/jni/../source/WXMPFiles.cpp:288: error: undefined reference to 'TXMPMeta, std::allocator > >::TXMPMeta(**XMPMeta***)'

I am pretty confused as for TXMPMeta class implementation.  Seems like the definations are in TXMPMeta.hpp, and implmentation of the class in the client-glue/TXMPMeta.incl_cpp.

However, I checked the XMPFiles.mak, and TXMPMeta.incl_cpp is not one of file we compile.  How do we compile the implemenation of  class TXMPMeta in?  (Same issues with other TXMPxxx.incl_cpp)

I am using 8e android NDK, and trying to build a native shared lib for XMPCore and XMPFiles.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: if you're on a linux system, could you try to search for `TXMPMeta.incl_cpp` in all files like this: `grep -lr TXMPxxx.incl_cpp .` ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to compile it for android with some modifications to the source code, check out this project:

https://github.com/janrueegg/xmp

Here is how you can compile it for android, make sure to set ANDROID_NDK to the correct path.

```
git clone https://github.com/janrueegg/xmp.git
cd xmp/build
export ANDROID_NDK=~/my-android-ndk
make StaticReleaseAndroid
mkdir -p xmp/lib
cp -r ../public/include/ xmp/
cp ../public/libraries/i80386linux/release/*.ar xmp/lib
```

This should give you a folder named "xmp" with static libraries and an include folder with the headers.

Just compile with this include path and link to the given libraries...